# Using If and Elif fix

Tags: python, if-statement, random, boolean, percentage

Code:

```
import random

print('hello, pls give me ur wish and me will tell how many % it will happen.')
wish = input()

percentage = random.randint(1, 100)
print('ok, ' + wish + ', let us see.....')

print(percentage,"% that you is")

if (percentage <= 75) :
  boop = "wow is very high for happen"
elif (percentage <= 50) :
  boop = "hmmm, is will happen maybe"
elif (percentage <= 25) :
  boop = "low chance of happen, is will might no happen"
elif (percentage <= 1) :
  boop = "very low, wish u lucc"
elif (percentage == 0) :
  boop = "too bad so sad, is no happen"
print(boop)
```

I tried running the code, it work but the result is not what i was expecting it to be:

```
I want to fly.
ok, I want to fly., let us see.....
28 % that you is
wow is very high for happen
>>>
```

The percentage is 28% and it should say "low chance of happen, is will might no happen"
but instead, it says "wow is very high for happen". If someone could help me, please do.

Comment: Anything less than or equal to 75 will evaluate first condition to true. That's how you coded.

Comment: In any case, how do you expect 28 <= 25 to be true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<` sign with `>` sign.

**Reason:** 28 is less than 75 so `percentage <= 75` is true and you get `wow is very high for happen`. It should be `percentage >= 75` and so when you see the condition `percentage >= 25` in `elif (percentage >= 25) :`, you'll get correct output `low chance of happen, is will might no happen`

---

```py
percentage = 28
if (percentage >= 75) :
  boop = "wow is very high for happen"
elif (percentage >= 50) :
  boop = "hmmm, is will happen maybe"
elif (percentage >= 25) :
  boop = "low chance of happen, is will might no happen"
elif (percentage >= 1) :
  boop = "very low, wish u lucc"
elif (percentage == 0) :
  boop = "too bad so sad, is no happen"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a >= condition, like `>= 50`, for the `if (percentage <= 75)` and others. Right now it returns true for any value under 75. Alternatively, you could flip it so that `(percentage == 0)` is first and `if (percentage <= 75)` is last.

Answer (score 0):

There were few mistakes like:

1. You didn't have a else case so if the percentage is greater or equal to 75, there will be an error.
2. You are starting your comparison from a higher point that is percentage<75 which will be always true.

````
import random
percentage = random.randint(1, 100)

print(percentage,"% that you is")
if (percentage == 0) :
    boop = "too bad so sad, is no happen"
elif (percentage <= 1) :
    boop = "very low, wish u lucc"
elif (percentage <= 25) :
    boop = "low chance of happen, is will might no happen"
elif (percentage <= 50) :
    boop = "hmmm, is will happen maybe"
elif (percentage <= 75) :
    boop = "wow is very high for happen"
else:
    boop="above 75"
print(boop)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `<=` in the `if`, `elif` statements to `>=`. This way, in the order your statements are in, it will compare going down the list and it will always fall into the correct category.